# Java - add a space after splitting a String

Tags: java

I need to add a space after splitting a String with a `" "` delimiter. The reason I need to do this is because a space has not been added at the start of the next String as shown in this example:

```
"There was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice" +
"think it so VERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to"
```

My code below only splits the string (and reverses it), but the concatenations produce the following result (Notice where "Alicethink" is joined together):

```
erehT saw gnihton os YREV elbakramer ni ;taht ron did knihtecilA
ti os YREV hcum tuo fo eht yaw ot raeh eht tibbaR yas
```

Code:

```
String[] text = PROBLEM5PARA.split(" ");
String reverseString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

    String word = text[i];
    String reverseWord = "";

    for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        reverseWord += word.charAt(j);
    }

    reverseString += reverseWord + " ";
}

System.out.println(reverseString);
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT:
Here is the whole String:

```
private static final String PROBLEM5PARA =
        "  There was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice" +
                "think it so VERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to" +
                "itself, `Oh dear!  Oh dear!  I shall be late!'  (when she thought" +
                "it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have" +
                "wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural);" +
                "but when the Rabbit actually TOOK A WATCH OUT OF ITS WAISTCOAT-" +
                "POCKET, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to" +
                "her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never" +
                "before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to" +
                "take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the" +
                "field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop" +
                "down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.";
```

Comment: How could you tell which word should be seperated after split ?

Answer (score 1):

If the original string is

```
"There was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice" + "think it so VERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to"
```

that is seen by your code as

```
"There was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alicethink it so VERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to"
```

After that concatenation (which happens in compilation, I believe), `Alicethink` is a single word, and there is no way to reverse `Alice` and `think` individually.

If this is a homework assignment, I think your code is currently doing what it's supposed to. If there is doubt, ask your instructor.

Comment: Thanks, it is a homework assignment and the task is complete I am asking just out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your original string is also joined `Alice" + "think`, you need update it to `Alice " +"think` or `Alice" + " think`

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a way to do this after the String has been set.

Comment: @JamesB no, there isn't.